# ag-grid custom loader as directive

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid-angular in my project. I am using more than 20 times ag-grid-angular in different pages of my App. Here i am using custom loader before loading the data. I need to use the custom loader as directive so i can re use in all my ag-grid-angular. But right now i can only able to declare loading template in each component.

```
<ag-grid-angular
    style="width:100%;height:300px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [overlayLoadingTemplate]="loadingTemplate"
    [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
```

and in component.ts

```
this.loadingTemplate = "<b>Example Loader</b>"
```

Please provide suggestion for one code use anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't want to define `this.loaderTemplate` in each component, right?

Comment: Yes i dont want to do so. Instead in my directive i will specify my HTML for loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with a directive which can inject grid component in constructor:

**ag-grid-loading.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";
import { AgGridNg2 } from "ag-grid-angular";

@Directive({
  selector: "ag-grid-angular"
})
export class AgGridLoadingDirective {
  constructor(private grid: AgGridNg2) {
    grid.overlayLoadingTemplate = "<b>Example Loader</b>";
  }
}
```

Make sure, that this directive is visible accross all your NgModules.

Now, you can remove `overlayLoadingTemplate` binding from all your grids.

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-install-and-simple-example-angular-7-sscmcd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fag-grid-loading.directive.ts)**